# Hacer una cuenta groupby con dask

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero saber cómo hacer un contador en cada fecha separada de mi DataFrame:

```
Index(['Date', 'Lang', 'Unique Open Email ID', 'User ID'], dtype='object')
```

Entonces intenté:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df_loe = dd.read_csv('last_opened_emails.csv')
df_loe.groupby(df_loe.Date).count().show()
```

Pero me devuelve:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-930b8f3e58b3> in <module>()
      2 df_loe = dd.read_csv('last_opened_emails.csv')
      3 # df_loe.columns
----> 4 df_loe.groupby(df_loe.Date).count().show()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py in __getattr__(self, key)
   3993             return self[key]
   3994         else:
-> 3995             raise AttributeError("'DataFrame' object has no attribute %r" % key)
   3996 
   3997     def __dir__(self):

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'show'
```

Answer (score 0):

Los objetos `DataFrame` no tienen el atributo `.show()` que es lo que te dice el error. Es decir estás llamando a un método que no existe.

Si quieres mostrar un Dataframe puedes usar `.head(n_filas)` donde `n_filas` es el número de filas que quieres mostrar.

Si estás usando `Dask` entiendo que tu tabla de datos es tan grande que no cabe en la memoria RAM de tu ordenador, por tanto si muestras más filas de las que pueden ser almacenadas en RAM tu ordenador colapsará por falta de memoria.

Si tienes suficiente RAM, puedes utilizar el método `.compute()` este ejecutará todas las operaciones que hayas realizado en el `DataFrame` por lo que puede tardar un tiempo. Tu código quedaría así:

```
df_loe.groupby(df_loe.Date).count().compute()
```

## Bonus

Recordemos que Dask es una librería que utiliza Pandas como base, pero que funciona con grafos y [lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation#:%7E:text=In%20programming%20language%20theory%2C%20lazy,avoids%20repeated%20evaluations%20). Es decir está pensada para trabajar con `DataFrames` que son enormes y no caben en la memoria RAM del ordenador. Lo que hace DASK es ir acumulando la lista de operaciones en un grafo y solo las ejecutará si nosotros se lo indicamos, por ejemplo con el método `compute()`